# Acumatica Error: 'AP Sub.' cannot be empty

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica I am trying to update payment instructions on a location for a supplier and it wont allow me to save saying Error: 'AP Sub.' cannot be empty.

I am not using sub accounts at all and the GL accounts tab is filled out.

After getting the message a trace shows the following:

Error:  Error: 'AP Sub.' cannot be empty.      Send
Raised At: 26/06/2017 1:19:58 AM    Screen: AP.30.30.10 Command: Save

26/06/2017 1:19:58 AM Error: 
Error: 'AP Sub.' cannot be empty.

```
    at MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.Extensions.AP.VendorLocationMaintExtension.Location_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs args, PXRowPersisting handler) 
   at PX.Data.PXRowPersisting.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() 
   at PX.Objects.CR.LocationMaint.Persist() 
   at PX.Objects.AP.VendorLocationMaint.Persist() 
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with a code snippet, stack trace, and some specific details so everyone can better understand your issue?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code from the Trace.  If you need more information please let me know what you need and where I need to go in order to get it.  Please note this is a cloud deployed application and I do not have direct access to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on attached stack trace, the exception is thrown inside Location_RowPersisting event handler declared within the **MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.Extensions.AP.VendorLocationMaintExtension** class. I would recommend contacting MYOB support and ask them to further review this issue.